# There was an error deploying functions when deploying my hosting

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

My code project is a Nextjs@12.2.2

When I upload my functions using: firebase deploy --only functions, they are upload successfully

```
=== Deploying to 'casavelerosbot-evbl'...

i  deploying functions
i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is     enabled...
✔  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged /Users/luisquiroga/Documents/GitHub/casavelerosweb/functions         (109.88 KB) for uploading
✔  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: updating Node.js 16 function onAccountCreate(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 16 function createProperty(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 16 function editProperty(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 16 function addMember(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 16 function removeMember(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 16 function createReservation(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 16 function editReservation(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 16 function updateReservationStatus(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 16 function removeReservation(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 16 function createTransaction(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 16 function editTransaction(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 16 function removeTransaction(us-central1)...
✔  functions[createTransaction(us-central1)] Successful update operation.
✔  functions[removeReservation(us-central1)] Successful update operation.
✔  functions[editProperty(us-central1)] Successful update operation.
✔  functions[editTransaction(us-central1)] Successful update operation.
✔  functions[removeMember(us-central1)] Successful update operation.
✔  functions[removeTransaction(us-central1)] Successful update operation.
✔  functions[editReservation(us-central1)] Successful update operation.
✔  functions[createReservation(us-central1)] Successful update operation.
✔  functions[updateReservationStatus(us-central1)] Successful update operation.
✔  functions[createProperty(us-central1)] Successful update operation.
✔  functions[addMember(us-central1)] Successful update operation.
✔  functions[onAccountCreate(us-central1)] Successful update operation.
i  functions: cleaning up build files...

✔  Deploy complete!
```

As you can see, there is no function called "ssrcasavelerosbotevbl", so I guess the issue is not with my functions.

Then for some reason when I run

```
firebase deploy --only hosting
```

The command build my web, then it tries to deploy **hosting AND functions**, when I explicitly said --only hosting.

Well this behavior has been the same since day 1 with this project (in other projects I'm able to only upload/update my website), but it has not been an issue till 3 days ago, when I try to do the firebase deploy --only hosting, this is the console output:

```
=== Deploying to 'casavelerosbot-evbl'...

i  deploying functions, hosting
i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment
i  functions: preparing codebase firebase-frameworks-casavelerosbot-evbl for deployment
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
⚠  functions: package.json indicates an outdated version of firebase-functions. Please upgrade using npm install --save firebase-functions@latest in your functions directory.
⚠  functions: Please note that there will be breaking changes when you upgrade.
i  functions: Loaded environment variables from .env.
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged /Users/luisquiroga/Documents/GitHub/casavelerosweb/functions (159.33 KB) for uploading
i  functions: preparing .firebase/casavelerosbot-evbl/functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged     /Users/luisquiroga/Documents/GitHub/casavelerosweb/.firebase/casavelerosbot-evbl/functions (21.22 MB) for uploading
i  functions: ensuring required API run.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API eventarc.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API pubsub.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API storage.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  functions: required API pubsub.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API storage.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API run.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API eventarc.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: generating the service identity for pubsub.googleapis.com...
i  functions: generating the service identity for eventarc.googleapis.com...
✔  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
✔  functions: .firebase/casavelerosbot-evbl/functions folder uploaded successfully
i  hosting[casavelerosbot-evbl]: beginning deploy...
i  hosting[casavelerosbot-evbl]: found 71 files in .firebase/casavelerosbot-evbl/hosting
✔  hosting[casavelerosbot-evbl]: file upload complete
i  functions: creating Node.js 16 function firebase-frameworks-casavelerosbot-evbl:ssrcasavelerosbotevbl(us-central1)...
⚠  functions: HTTP Error: 400, Could not create Cloud Run service ssrcasavelerosbotevbl. spec.template.spec.containers.resources.limits.cpu: Invalid value specified for cpu. For the specified value, maxScale may not exceed 10.
Consider running your workload in a region with greater capacity, decreasing your requested cpu-per-instance, or requesting an increase in quota for this region if you are seeing sustained usage near this limit, see https://cloud.google.com/run/quotas. Your project may gain access to further scaling by adding billing information to your account.
⚠  functions: failed to create function projects/casavelerosbot-evbl/locations/us-central1/functions/ssrcasavelerosbotevbl
Failed to create function projects/casavelerosbot-evbl/locations/us-central1/functions/ssrcasavelerosbotevbl

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
    firebase-frameworks-casavelerosbot-evbl:ssrcasavelerosbotevbl(us-central1)
i  functions: cleaning up build files...

Error: There was an error deploying functions
```

So I don't know why it is asking for a ssrcasavelerosbotevbl function. I have removed that function a long time ago.

So because of the behavior an this error, I am not able to update my webpage

firebase.json:

```html
{
  "functions": [
    {
      "source": "functions",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "source": ".",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "frameworksBackend": {
      "region": "us-central1"
    }
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  }
}
```

package.json of my frontend

```html
{
  "name": "casavelerosweb",
  "version": "0.1.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build && next export",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@date-io/moment": "^2.16.1",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
    "@fontsource/roboto": "^4.5.8",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.0",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.122",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.4",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.11.2",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^5.0.13",
    "@next/font": "13.1.2",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.7",
    "eslint": "8.31.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.1.2",
    "firebase": "^9.18.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^11.5.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "next": "12.2.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-firebase-hooks": "^5.1.1",
    "react-firebaseui": "^6.0.0"
  }
}
```

package.json of functions

```html
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^11.5.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.2.1",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "twilio": "^2.5.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.9.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

[image: Image of all my functions in firebase]

Comment: You mentioned that in other projects you are able to update the website using `firebase deploy --only hosting` does that other project also have the same firebase.json as this one ?

Comment: @RohitKharche Yes it is very similar

Comment: The error message specifically states that there was an issue with the value specified for the cpu limit and that the maxScale may not exceed 10. This may indicate that you are trying to allocate more CPU resources than the region where you are deploying to can handle. So I recommend you to lower your resources while deploying

Comment: @RohitKharche how do you do that?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding maxInstances to my firebase.json

```
{
  "functions": {
"source": "functions"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "source": ".",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "frameworksBackend": {
      "region": "us-central1",
      "maxInstances": 2
    }
  }
}
```